# Find position of word in string

Tags: mysql, sql, string, csv, mariadb

I have string

```
good morning what a lovely day today
```

I need to find the position of `'lovely'`. Query should return the result `5`.

Comment: string is coming from a column of table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find_in_set()` for this:

```
select find_in_set('lovely', replace('good morning what a lovely day today', ' ', ','))
```

Yields:

```
 5
```

From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

> `FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)`
>
> Returns a value in the range of `1` to `N` if the string `str` is in the string list `strlist` consisting of `N` substrings. A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by `,` characters.

So basically the logic is to replace space characters with commas, and then use that function.

Comment: Thanks it worked. One more help. The output which came i need to pass it in the below query   SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(INFO,'/List/Attribute[XX]/Value') ADDRESS_1 FROM INFO WHERE ID = 'TEST;

Comment: where XX is the result retrieved from the 1st query

Comment: @user1251973: something like `EXTRACTVALUE(INFO, CONCAT('/List/Attribute', find_in_set('lovely', replace(INFO, ' ', ','), '/Value'))`

Comment: its not working....given error

Comment: SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(INFO, CONCAT('/List/Attribute[', find_in_set('LOVELY', replace(INFO, ' ', ','), ']/Value')) FROM INFO WHERE ID = 'TEST;

Comment: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'find_in_set'

Comment: Yes there is a misplace parenthese: `EXTRACTVALUE(INFO, 
 CONCAT('/List/Attribute', find_in_set('lovely', replace(INFO, ' ', ',')), '/Value'))`

Comment: one more error ERROR 1105 (HY000): Only constant XPATH queries are supported

Comment: can you please help?